# Find the area between the cardoid $r=a(1+\cos \theta)$ and the circle $r=\frac {3a}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, area, polar-coordinates

Find the area between the cardoid $r=a(1+\cos \theta)$ and the circle $r=\frac {3a}{2}$

My Attempt:

Here, the cardioid is $r=a(1+\cos \theta)$ and the circle is $r=\frac {3a}{2}$. Solving these two equations:
$$\frac {3a}{2}=a(1+\cos \theta)$$
$$\cos \theta=\frac {1}{2}$$
$$\theta=\frac {\pi}{3}$$
Thus, the point of intersection is $(\frac {3a}{2},\frac {\pi}{3})$.
How to proceed further?

Comment: consider also $r=-\frac{3a}{2}$ and $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(\theta) = a(1+\cos \theta) - \frac{3a}{2}$

It is easy to observe that $f(\theta) = f(-\theta)$, hence the graph is symmetric about x-axis

Further, for $f(\theta) < 0$, the cardoid is inside the circle, and will be the function to integrate, and vice versa for $f(\theta ) > 0$

After this setup, what we get as the area is

$$A = 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3a}{2}\right)^2d\theta + 2\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^\pi\frac{1}{2}a^2(1+\cos \theta)^2d\theta$$

The factor of two comes from symmetry about x-axis